# ASP.NET Web site (NOT WEB APP) Bundle js and css

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, bundler

I have the following configured

Class called BudleConfig in the App_Code Folder

```
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Class BundleConfig
  Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(bundles As BundleCollection)

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WerbFormsJs").Include(
                "~/js/Global.min.js",
                "~/js/bootstrp.min.js"
    ))


   End Sub
End Class
```

Next in a Global.asax

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs on application startup

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    End Sub
```

Finally in the Header User Control used on all pages

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
         <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WerbFormsJs") %>          
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

However, **Scripts** is giving me Build Errors - 'Scripts' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I also added the following to the Web.config

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to fully qualify the Scripts.Render as follows:

```
 <%: Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WerbFormsJs") %>
```

Problem resolved.